# How to disable and enable button in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects with delete button hidden when page loads. Now I want to show the delete button when new object is pushed to the array, the existing objects button should still remain hidden. How do I hide existing buttons and only show new object delete button.

**html**

```
<div>
 <table >
   <tr>//.....</tr>
   <tr *ngFor="list of Array1">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
          (click)=remove(i) [disabled]="disabled">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td>{{list.type}}</td>
      <td>{{list.year}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div>
 <table >
   <tr>//.....</tr>
   <tr *ngFor="list of Array2">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
          (click)=addObj(i)>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td>{{list.type}}</td>
      <td>{{list.year}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Here is the code used for adding new object from another array:

**ts**

```
//..
disabled = false;

....
addObj(index) {
   // is there a way I can enable the delete button of just the index pushed?
   this.Array1.push(this.List[index]);
   this.List.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking! I mean modify `disabled` variable to `true`. Are you using that button in the forloop? have you missed some HTML part from question?

Comment: Not clear with your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have lists of objects in a array which I displayed with ngFor. Every roll has delete button and when the app loads I made all delete button hidden. Now if I want to push new object to the array (from another array) I want the button of the new object visible.

Comment: @Pleasure Post All related HTML code and TS code! forLoop and sample data

Comment: if you set disabled to false then `*ngIf="disabled"` will always hide the button instead of disabling the button. instead use disabled attribute on button. `[disabled]="disabled"`

Answer (score 9):

#### Define a variable to `show/hide` the button

```
isDisabled = true;
```

Then change the variable state in your code where you are pushing new items to the array. It could be any method or inside subscriber etc.

```
this.isDisabled = false; // or this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
```

then in your button bind disabled `attribute` with this `isDisabled` variable.

```
[disabled]="isDisabled"
```

Complete Button Example

```
<button (click)="delete(item.id)" [disabled]="isDisabled">Delete</button>
```

Comment: This solution does not work I have tried it before. When I pushed new object, it enables all other existing buttons.

Comment: yes it will enable all buttons because all buttons are using same variable's value. setting changing its value will enable all buttons or disable all buttons. the exact solution for this problem is to keep a new `key: value` pair of `disabled: false` to each object. then bind `object.disabled` in your button with `[disabled]` attribute. when you push new items to array then set disabled to true. this can be done by .filter and .map function of JavaScript.

Comment: What I did now was to use 2 diff arrays to hold the new and the old obj separated. It seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
    (click)=remove(i) [disabled]="!show">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>button
</button>



//..
show = false;

....
addObj(index) {
   // is there a way I can enable the delete button of just the index pushed?
   this.Array1.push(this.List[index]);
   this.show = true;
   this.List.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Comment: I did something like this but it only show all the buttons including the existing once. I want to only show for the new obj

Comment: try creating different variables like "show" for enabling and disabling other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `dummy array` containing the `index` of newly added `object`. And then make condition on that `array` in `*ngIf`.

**Html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
    (click)=remove(i) *ngIf="deleteButtonShowIndex.indexOf(i) !== -1">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</button>
```

**Component**

```
deleteButtonShowIndex = [];
addObj(index) {
   deleteButtonShowIndex.push(index);
   this.Array1.push(this.List[index]);
   this.List.splice(index, 1)
}
```

The better approach I will suggest is to maintain a flag in `this.Array1` as shown below:

```
this.Array1 = [{
    show: false,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    show: false,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    show: true,
    data: {}
  }
];
```

Comment: Yes, but I was having one issue, that is the button of the new object was showing on wrong/first existing object. The reason was because the existing object's button was hidden. Can you play around the same solution but using [disabled]="disabled" so that the new obj button stays on the same roll?

Comment: Put the condition in disabled but remove !(not)

Comment: It is the first index button that is enabled! Why that? The new index button was disabled but the first existing index button was enabled, why?

Comment: Your solution seem to work but enabling wrong button

Comment: How you made the condition. Please paste it here!

Comment: [disabled]="deleteButtonShowIndex.indexOf(i) == -1"

Comment: You want to make newly added button enable right? If so then it should work.

Comment: The thing is, I am having 3 objects in the array and with ur solution the buttons we disabled onloading. But when I push new object to the array, the button of the current obj got disabled and the button of the first obj got activated instead. Why that?

Comment: Can you show me some piece of code where you are using *ngFor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204203/discussion-between-pleasure-and-surjeet-bhadauriya).

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property `showButton` which will be used to decide whether button will be displayed or not. And when you insert a new record make this `showButton` property to true which will lead to show the button like shown in the demo. Then in your template you can easily use `*ngIf` to decide whether to show the button or not.

> app.component.html

```
<button (click)="addButtonHandler()">
  add record
</button>

<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor = "let val of item">
    <td>{{val.name}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="val.showButton"><button>click me</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> app.component.ts

```
 name = 'Angular';
 item:Item[]=[]
  constructor(){
    this.item.push({
        'name':'Monica',
        'showButton':false
    })

    this.item.push({
        'name':'Rachel',
        'showButton':false
    })
  }

  addButtonHandler(){
    this.item.push({
      'name':'phoebe',
      'showButton':true
    })
  }
```

Working demo: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtbzdp)

Comment: Your demo looks ok but it could not help me because I cannot hard code the buttons.

Comment: @Pleasure can you share your code on stackblitz such that we have something to work on.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve the same result as your solution without hard coding 'showButton'?

Comment: @Pleasure when you say `I have an array of objects with delete button hidden when page loads.`  how you have created these button and how they are hidden?

Comment: Sorry for that, my json did not contain button, I included a button td in the *ngFor. See the updated html in the question. The buttons of Array1 is disabled and when new index is pushed to Array1 from Array2, I want only the delete button of only the new index to be active.